# Retrieve 2 values and insert into a string with one call

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I created the below function to get FirstName and LastName and place them into a string FullName.

My linq statement looks a bit funny as I am doing 2 queries on the same row to get the information I need.

Is there a better way of coding this?

```
public static string getMemberFullNamebyID(int memID)
{
    using (var ctx = new GPEntities())
    {
        string fname = string.Empty;
        string lname = string.Empty;

        fname = ctx.Members.Where(g => g.memID == memID).Select(g => g.memFirstName).FirstOrDefault();
        lname = ctx.Members.Where(g => g.memID == memID).Select(g => g.memLastName).FirstOrDefault();

        return (lname + ", " + lname).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
ctx.Members.Where(g => g.memID == memID)
    .Select(g => g.memFirstName + ", " + g.memLastName).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the values separately, use anonymous type, example:

```
var ret = ctx.Members.Where(g => g.memID == memID)
    .Select(g => new { First = g.memFirstName, Last = g.memLastName}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Accessing the anonymous type:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("WoLfulus");
list.Add("David");

var sel = list.Select(i => new { 
    Normal = i, 
    Lower = i.ToLower(), 
    Upper = i.ToUpper() 
});
```

Accessing the returned data:

```
foreach (var str in sel)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(str.Normal + ", " + str.Lower + ", " + str.Upper);
}
```

Output:

```
WoLfulus, wolfulus, WOLFULUS
David, david, DAVID
```

If not, use what AdaTheDev said.

Comment: How would you access the Anonymous types? I am using 
----------
memFullName = ctx.Members.Where(g => g.memID == memID).Select(g => g.memLastName + ", " + g.memFirstName).FirstOrDefault() 
----

Comment: Just as @WoLfulus wrote above with "var". You could also create a Tuple or an instance of a custom type if you need the result outside the method.

Comment: @DavidKEgghead I've edited the answer with a better example. I'm doing an iteration because I'm not selecting only one object, but a list.